# Strange behavior of some zip files while extracting (7zip)

Tags: powershell, unzip

I have a problem with unzipping files. Usually I use a PowerShell script, that I run through SQL Server database (procedure) and it will unzip my files how I want them (database shouldn't be any issue).

Main part of script:

```
exec '"for %i in ("'+@path+'\*.zip") do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%i" -o"'+@to+'""'
```

But for once in a while there is a .zip file that if run through this script will extract files with names of files encoded badly and to prevent that I need to manually open every .zip file and click to extract in 7-zip GUI and that will returns names of files correctly.

This manual way of doing things very, very slow. Because it needs to be done on a server, God forbids if I am on VPN at home. So let's say I have 5 zip files (3 GB), it will take me hours to unzip. If I do it, through server it takes like 2 minutes.

So I just trying to find out how to unzip it with script, what is the difference between my script and manual extraction?

Comment: This looks more like a problem of 7z and most probably has nothing to do with the database or script. 
Take a look at this for example https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/bugs/2198/

Comment: Yes, I know that my script is correct and db has no issue. I just dont know what is the problem or how to modify my script to replicate gui behavior. But I will definitly read that.

Comment: Not that what you're showing is `cmd.exe` code, not PowerShell.

Comment: Does `expand-archive` work instead?

Comment: So can it be that the files contain files that were originally non utf-8 (asian countries)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root-cause is likely to be files that were created with a setup that doesn't match the codepage of your windows environment. Are any of the zip file publicly available? If so, can you provide a link?

To deal with these problem files, you need to know what encoding was used for the filenames. If the `7z` gui can handle these files automatically there must be an option to tell it what encoding to use.

Once you know the encoding you can use the `-scs` option in `7z` to decode the filenames correctly.

Modern zip files don't have this issue because they store filenames in UTF-8.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer! I will definitly try that. Sadly I cant provide you with a sample of files and as for used encoding, I will need to ask the guys that sent it to us.